# Runescape is installed on my kali build but will not launch

Tags: kali-linux

I am trying to install and run runescape into my kali build. I have "successfully" installed all dependencies and have run the instructions to install from the official site. It is listed in my app menu but when i click it, nothing launches. I have a feeling it has to do with root privileges. If not, any help would be much appreciated. I am a new user so i can only add the screenshot as they allow. it is simply a picture of runescape in my app menu.

[screenshot of runescape in app menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GzWN.png)

Comment: _"The fact of the matter is, however, that Kali is a Linux distribution specifically geared towards professional penetration testers and security specialists, and given its unique nature, it is **NOT** a recommended distribution if you’re unfamiliar with Linux or are looking for a general-purpose Linux desktop distribution for development, web design, **gaming**, etc."_ - from [Should I Use Kali Linux?](https://docs.kali.org/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux)

Comment: Well, yes, I know that. However just getting this far has increased my general knowledge of Linux and how to use it. From my limited knowledge i have a feeling that launching everything as root is what is hindering me. My guess would be to somehow access the code which runs on the machine and change just a couple lines to be able to launch successfully.

Can you at least tell me if im getting warmer here?
or any other way to eat this particular reese's

Comment: So i have deduced that i need to install libpng12-0 for debian 7, but am having trouble finding it on google. I have also tried temporarily adding the debian 7 repository to my sources.list using leafpad. That did not work.

I have googled people having a similar issue of installing libpng12 and this page is the one that has helped me to deduce i may need the libpng12-0 package for debian 7 "wheezy".

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/331803/cannot-install-libpng12-0-on-debian/520725#520725